# how to chain where query in rails 3 active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to add conditions depending on params data.

```
@users = User.where('id', params[:id]) unless params[:id].nil?
@users = User.where('email', params[:email]) unless params[:email].nil?
@users = User.limit(10)
```

But it does not work for some reason.
Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Each of your statements is replacing the `@users` variable, and as ActiveRecord evaluates each lazily, the first two are never being called.

If you want to maintain three separate queries and build things up that way you can do:

```
@users = User.limit(10)
@users = @users.where('id', params[:id]) if params[:id]
@users = @users.where('email', params[:email]) if params[:email]
```

It isn't the prettiest, but it will work. However, I recommend keeping it to a single method call and defining it in the model.

```
# In the model

def self.by_id_and_email(id, email)
  users = limit(10)
  users = users.where('id', id)       if id.present?
  users = users.where('email', email) if email.present?

  users
end

# In the controller / out of the model

User.by_id_and_email(params[:id], params[:email])
```

That way you can use the method again, refine it, and write speed(ier) tests against it.

Comment: that worked, do you know if there is a way to do it without a limit query on first line?

Comment: You can just use `scoped` instead, `users = scoped`, which returns an ActiveRecord::Relation object that has nothing applied.

Answer (score 7):

You could add scopes to your model that don't do anything if the param isn't provided e.g.
(the scoped call just returns the current scope)

```
# in the model

def self.by_id(id)
    return scoped unless id.present?
  where(:id => id)
end

def self.by_email(email)
  return scoped unless email.present?
  where(:email => email)
end


# in the controller

User.by_id(params[:id]).by_email(params[:email])
```

Comment: Just what i was looking for!

Comment: I had to substitute `all` for `scoped` as I believe `scoped` is deprecated in this context.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this simply by:

```
wheres = [:id, :email].map{|key| params.has_key?(key) ? {key => params[key]} : {} }\
                      .inject({}){|hash, injected| hash.merge!(injected)}
@users = User.where(wheres).limit(10)
```

Further, you could always abstract the above into a scope.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect case for scopes. Check out this asciicast for a more in depth tutorial: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3

By using scopes you can keep the where clauses as separate elements that you can reuse individually, but can also chain them just like the where clauses.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via something like...

```
if params[:id].exists? && params[:email].exists?
  @users = User.where('id = ? AND email = ?', params[:id], params[:email]).limit(10)
elsif #if only one of id/email exists then...
  @users = User.where( #conditions for only one of id/email ).limit(10)
else
  #raise some errors
```

Comment: actually i have more then two params (might be up to 5 different params for filtering)

Comment: you down vote me because you didn't explain your question properly?

Answer (score 0):

Actually is better if you create Scopes for example, [This is a excellent article that explain this](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/)

in your model

```
scope :by_id, -> id { where(id: id) if id.present? }
scope :by_email, -> email { where(email: email) if email.present? }
```

and in your method you can call in this way

```
def my_function()
    User.by_id(id).by_email(email)
end
```